# Constraining locators

Tags: manipulate, locator

Is there any canonical way to constrain locators either continuously (e.g. to lie on the graph of a function) or discretely (snap to grid leaps to mind)? The documentation seems a little sketchy on the subject...

Comment: Please look at the questions under "related" in the right column on this page. This has been done many times before using the second argument of `Dynamic`.

Comment: For a curve represented as an implicit Cartesian equation, I used `RegionNearest[]` for [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/127781). If you need locators to be constrained to a function, see [this](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LocatorPane.html#148449963) (a similar approach should work for parametrically-defined curves).

Comment: @C.E. Ah, I see! My browser was not showing me this before, for some reason - I did not have any doubt that the question was not exactly new...

Comment: [**29888**](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/29888/5478), [**47221**](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/47221/5478) etc.